# CI 2.2.x upgrade to CI 3.0.x core files issues

Tags: mysqli, codeigniter-2, upgrade, codeigniter-3, php-5.6

I just followed the [upgrade guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html) for CI2 to CI3 and don't have encountered any other issues so far. Will probably get some because of the project I converted still uses DataMapper and has some other hooks and third party tools.

So the first problem I encountered so far is that my custom core controllers don't work anymore.

I use for example this depth for my front-end and back-end logic:

- CI_Controller > MY_Controller > CronController
- CI_Controller > MY_Controller > FrontendController
- CI_Controller > MY_Controller > AdminController

CI3 tells me that my `controllers/Account.php` controller doesn't know the `FrontendController` class.

Can I tell CI3 to still include my custom classes or is there a new approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `__autoload(){$class}` for autoloading your core classes, you should change it with `spl_autoload_register(function ($class){}`. I.e.:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT)) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I did something else wrong. When I looked at the CI3 autoloader, I noticed that it wanted the core controllers to be "FrontendController.php", thus with Controller also starting with a capital. Once I changed the three files with the correct double capital, it was ok. Thanks!